# iOS application is crashing when user presses back on ios13

Tags: ios, uitableview, crash, uikit, ios13

My application is working fine on all iOS versions. But on one view controller, when user presses back the application crashes `only on iOS13`.

I have tried to add breakpoints in `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` & `Exceptional Breakpoint`, but no crash stack is appearing in Xcode. Has anybody faced this weird issue in iOS 13? In addition to this, there is no useful information in the console.

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)

[image]

Comment: UIScrollView delegate method is getting called on click of back and ARC has release UIScrollview instance in between. Implement back action and set UIScrollview delegate to nil. It should resolved your issue.

Comment: @Bhumeshwerkatre thanks for the solution. I will try this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable Zombies for the app in order to debug and find the line causing this crash. [How to enable zombies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386160/how-to-enable-nszombie-in-xcode). After enabling Zombies Run your Xcode and go to instruments and start recording. Go back to your App and try generating the error. Instruments should detect bad call (to zombie) if there is one.

Hope it helps!